# Notepad++ RE Search and Replace

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

Can someone explain why the following record: 
1234 4567 blahblahblah

becomes 
blahblahblah

When Search/Replace applied (NP++ v6.9) with: 
Replace:^\d{4}\h
with:(nothing)
(Reg Exp) radio on

Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 3):

#### Can someone explain why `1234 4567 blahblahblah` becomes `blahblahblah`

> When Search/Replace applied with: "Find what": `^\d{4}\h`, "Replace with": `(nothing)` and  "Regular expression" is `enabled`.

- `^` - Is an anchor that matches the start of a line.
- `\d` - A digit in the `0-9` range.
- `{4}` - Matches 4 copies of the element it applies to.
- `\h` - Horizontal spacing. This only matches space, tab and line feed.

Putting it all together:

- `^\d{4}\h` - find 4 digits followed by a space, tab or a line feed at the start of a line.

So clicking "Replace" will replace `1234` with nothing leaving:

```
4567 blahblahblah
```

Clicking "Replace" again will replace `4567` with nothing leaving:

```
blahblahblah
```

Clicking "Replace all" instead of the first "Replace" will just performs replacements as many times as it can (2 in this case) leaving just:

```
blahblahblah
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score -1):

The expression is replacing 4 numerical characters with any leading white space with (nothing). If you use the 'Replace' button, '1234 ' will be removed. If you press 'Replace' again the remaining '4567 ' is removed. Thus, if you press 'Replace All' you will be left with 'blahblahblah'.

Comment: Incorrect explanation: 1/ "leading white space" should be "trailing **Horizontal** spacing (space, tab or line feed)" 2/ You don't mention that the expression is anchored to the start of the line with `^`.